# How to get the data submitted using POST on Python using Pyramid?

Tags: python, ajax, pyramid

I'm looking for the equivalent of PHP's $_POST[] in Python.
On PHP, when you submit a form you can get its value by using the $_POST[].
How can I get this data on python?
here is my code.

```
function NewUser(){
                    var firstName = $('#firstName').val();
                    var dataString = '&firstName='+firstName;
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url:"newusers",
                        data:dataString,
                        dataType:'text',
                        success:function(s){
                            alert(s);
                        },
                        error:function(){
                            alert('FAILED!');
                        }


                    })
                }
```

This is where I throw the data.

```
@view_config(route_name='newusers', renderer='json')
    def newusers(self):
    return '1';
```

This code works fine and it returns and alert a string "1".

My question is, how can I get the submitted firstName? and put it on the return instead of "1".

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another variation that should work:

```
@view_config(route_name='newusers', renderer='json')
def newusers(self):
    # Best to check for the case of a blank/unspecified field...
    if ('firstName' in self.request.params):
        name =  str(self.request.params['firstName'])
    else:
        name = 'null'
    return name
```

Note: Be careful using str() function, particularly in python 2.x, as it may not be compatible with unicode input using characters beyond ascii.  You might consider:

```
        name = (self.request.params['firstName']).encode('utf-8')
```

as an alternative.

Comment: i'll use this one! :D

Comment: All data in `request.params`, `request.POST` and `request.GET` will be strings (possibly empty ones) unless you did some post-processing to the data.

Comment: Agreed...the use of str() or encode() is really not necessary.  If a template contains multiple forms, it is possible that some are not used possibly resulting in nonexistent dict keys; that is why I recommend checking for the existence of a key before trying to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I manage to make it work with this code.

```
@view_config(route_name='newusers', renderer='json')
def newusers(self):
    name =  str(self.request.POST.get('firstName'))
    return name
```